# Google OAuth 2.0 Service Account vs Administrator Account

Tags: gmail, imap, google-oauth

This question is specific to google business/education accounts. I couldn't find any documentation on this. 
I have a server application that needs to access google mail inbox and check the read/delete status of certain messages based on filters. I need to do this without requesting user authorization or any involvement of the user.
Should I use an administrator account or a service account and what's the difference between the 2? 
Are there any limitations on how many mailboxes can be accessed and how often can they be accessed by an administrator account or service account?
For eg: IF I need to check 5000 mailboxes based on a filter, how frequently can I do this using an admin account or service account.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a service account. Admins have rights to manage Google Apps but authenticating to Gmail IMAP as the admin will only give you access to the admin user's mailbox.

There are no limitations I am aware of in terms of number of mailboxes that can be accessed but be aware of the [Gmail bandwidth limitations](http://support.google.com/a/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1071518) that may come into play depending on your workload. These limits are per-user, not per service account.

Comment: Thanks for your response! A user has a limitation of sending 2000 messages/day? Does this apply to the service account?

Comment: Yes, Google Appps for Business/EDU are limited to 2k emails/day/user. Service accounts don't send email except on behalf of a user which would count against the user quota.

Comment: Hi, My colleague is using this to login as domain administrator and connect to a user's inbox.http://www.limilabs.com/blog/2-legged-oauth-with-gmail   so, admin account imap access is possible?

Comment: No, that's not authenticating as the administrator, that's 2-legged OAuth which is the old OAuth 1.0 equivalent of OAuth 2.0 Service Accounts. 2-legged OAuth is deprecated, use Service Accounts.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification! Does Google have any kind of lab for proof of concept testing. We would like to have a service account and 1K users (preferably 5K users) to do some performance testing for a week or 2. Are you aware of any lab setup that we can use?

Comment: I am not aware of any way to get test accounts from Google.